Powershell process as administrator
I'm using following code to execute some powershell commands remotely:
Invoke-WmiMethod -ComputerName $ComputerHost -Credential $cred -Class Win32_Process -Name Create -ArgumentList "powershell -command $MyPowershellCommand" -ErrorAction Stop

My user has all needed permissions. I need to start powershell process with "Run as Administrator" argument. Could someone tell me what I need to add in ArgumentList block to achieve these?

Why not use PowerShell Remoting?

Yes. I know that we have a lot of stuff to execute commands remotely, but I need to use EXACTLY these one by many reasons which long to describe

You may want to look for runas.exe or -Verb RunAs.

"I need to use EXACTLY these one" sounds like an XY problem. Anyways, afaik, -Credential $cred defines your "My user has all needed permissions" You cannot elevate on demand in a remote session (the way you can locally, interactively with Start-Process -Verb RunAs). But I guess you getting a Access Denied type of error (do you? what is the exact error?) What are you trying to do? (in other words: what is in $MyPowershellCommand)?
